# Exterior tensor product of complexes of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry” by Daniel Huybrechts. In page 119, in Exercise 5.13, with the assumption $P_i\in D^b(X_i\times Y_i)$, $i=1,2$, he considers the exterior tensor product $P_1\boxtimes P_2\in D^b((X_1\times X_2)\times (Y_1\times Y_2))$. My question is that what is this exterior tensor product?